# What program do I use to check mail?

Tags: command-line, ubuntu, email, mail-user-agent

I'm receiving "You have mail" messages and according to [How to remove “You have mail” welcome message](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2432/250) I should read my mail with `mail`. However I cannot find the command in my system (Ubuntu 10.04 server). What do I need to install?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On Debian and derived distributions, you can use the `apt-file` command to search for a package containing a file. Install `apt-file` (`apt-get install apt-file`) and download its database (`apt-file update`, Ubuntu does it automatically if you're online). Then search for `bin/mail`:

```
apt-file -x search 'bin/mail$'
```

With the [`command-not-found`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/command-not-found) [image: Install command-not-found] package installed, if you type a command that doesn't exist but can be installed from the Ubuntu repositories, you get an informative message:

```
$ mail
The program 'mail' can be found in the following packages:
 * heirloom-mailx
 * mailutils
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

If you're not after `mail` specifically, but after any program to read your local mail from the command line, there are much better alternatives. All mail user agents provide the [`mail-reader`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/mail-reader) virtual package, so browse the list of packages that provide `mail-reader` and install one or more that looks good to you (and doesn't use a GUI, if it's for a server).

[`mutt`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/mutt) [image: Install mutt]'s motto is [“All mail clients suck. This one just sucks less.”](http://www.mutt.org/), and I tend to agree, but in the end it's a very personal choice.

Answer (score 11):

Another program you can use is `mutt`. I prefer using `mutt` to `mail` - it just has a nicer interface in my opinion.

```
# apt-get install mutt
```

should work - but I use Fedora not Ubuntu so can't confirm this.

Answer (score 10):

Just install [mailutils](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/lucid/+package/mailutils) which must contain [`mail`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/mail.1.html):

```
# apt-get install mailutils
```

Read more about mail and GNU mailutils [here](http://mailutils.org/manual/mailutils.html#SEC66)

Answer (score 2):

You may already have `mail` installed.  If so, you can read your mail by entering `mail` at the command line.

Welcome to the world of choice.  You can use pretty well any mail reader you choose.  `emacs` users can read mail from within their editor.

Install a `pop3` or `imap` server and you can read your mail from your Windows PC, Mac, or other devices.

If you setup a `.forward` or `.procmailrc` file then you may be able to forward your mail to another e-mail address and read it from there.