# How can I find where LANG, LANGUAGE and MAIL environmental variables are set?

Tags: bash, login, environment-variables

I've had a [few](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19854/how-can-i-change-the-locale) [issues](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144291/how-can-i-make-mailx-inform-me-of-new-mail) with environmental variables not set correctly in my Raspbmc Raspberry Pi. Specifically, I've had to manually specify the following in `~/.bashrc`.

```
export LANG='en_AU.UTF-8"
export LANGUAGE='en_AU:en'
export MAIL='/var/mail/pi'
```

However, in another Pi running vanilla Raspbian, these environmental variables *are* set correctly. I wanted to see what file specified these, but couldn't find it. I tested the files that I know of that run when logging in to a terminal. These gave no hits.

```
grep LANG -r /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/ /etc/bash.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bashrc /etc/environment
grep MAIL -r /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/ /etc/bash.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bashrc /etc/environment
```

Conversely, on my laptop running Arch, `/etc/profile.d/locale.sh` appears to set `LANG`, and `~/.profile` specifies `LANGUAGE`. However, I could find no mention of `MAIL`.

How can  I find where these environmental variables are set?

---

### EDIT

I searched the whole of `/etc` and `~` for these strings in the working system (Raspbian).

```
grep "\bMAIL=" -r /etc 2>/dev/null
grep "\bMAIL=" -r ~ 2>/dev/null
```

Searching for MAIL gave no hits.

```
grep "\bLANG=" -r /etc 2>/dev/null
grep "\bLANG=" -r ~ 2>/dev/null
```

This strategy gave only a few hits for LANG in `/etc`, and none for LANGUAGE. There were a few false hits in `/etc` with `LANG=C`, and one true hit (as [mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144415/how-can-i-find-where-lang-language-and-mail-environmental-variables-are-set?noredirect=1#comment232629_144415) by [vinc17](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/74516/vinc17)) at `/etc/default/locale:LANG=en_AU.UTF-8`. However (as per a [previous question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/19854/how-can-i-change-the-locale) by me), this file at `/etc/default/locale` is not sourced on my Raspbmc machine, so I presume that the situation is a bit more complicated than the mere presence of this file.

Comment: How about doing a recursive content search in the entire /etc, home, and other probable directories? `grep "\bLANG=" -r /etc 2>/dev/null` or `find /etc -type f -exec grep "\bLANG=" {} + 2>/dev/null`

Comment: Yes, you should recursive-grep the entire `/etc` directory. Under Debian, locales are set in `/etc/default/locale`.

Comment: Thanks @vinc17. This file is indeed present; I've edited the question.

Comment: Other possibilities are `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bash_login`.

Comment: @terdon, these files don't exist on the Raspbian.

Answer (score 2):

And just to confuse things more, if you log on remotely using SSH your SSH client is to allowed to override (some of) the system defaults with your client side settings/preferences...

This is governed by the `AcceptEnv` directives in the `sshd_config` file e.g. :

```
# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
```

Comment: Thanks again HBruijn. In the working Raspbian system, `grep AcceptEnv /etc/ssh/sshd_config` returns `AcceptEnv LANG LC_*`. On Raspbmc, `locate sshd_config` gives nothing. In Raspbian, I suppose the presence of `LANG` might explain this setting being inherited from the SSH client, but not `LANGUAGE`. Also, there is no mention of `MAIL` at all.