# Can program notify itself any opened shell?

Tags: command-line

I am planning on write CLI program. This CLI program should have ability to run at scheduled time.

Is it possible for this program to somehow notify user's shell? Sort of like `mail` tells you that you have unread mail?

Comment: You can run a shellscript via `cron`. Add a line in `crontab` for when to start the shellscript. You can find good tutorials about cron and crontab via the internet. The shellscript can write 'anywhere' according to where you tell it to write. You may need some special fix to allow writing to some places.

Comment: *"notify user's shell"* - what do you mean? Send a GUI notification?

Comment: meaning there would be some output in the user's shell, similarly to how `mail` program does it

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "shell". Desktop Environment? Terminal (emulator)?

Comment: terminal emulator

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, to send a GUI notification you could use:

- `notify-send`
- `xmessage`
- `zenity`

For more info

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/687132/can-i-make-centered-desktop-notifications
- https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/12/ubuntu-notify-send/
- https://superuser.com/questions/309961/linux-how-to-send-message-to-local-user-logged-into-x11

Answer (score 1):

Mail checks are implemented [in various shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2432/86440). Presumably you don’t want to get an additional check added to the shells your users are likely to use. To get a similar check, the simplest approach is to implement a tool which produces the appropriate output when a notification should be displayed, and run that from your users’ shell startup scripts.

There are various examples of this; if you check your system’s `/etc/profile.d`, you might find similar tools you can use as inspiration. For example, on systems with `abrt` (RHEL etc.), you’ll find an `abrt-console-notification.sh` script which displays `abrt`’s status when users log in.

Answer (score 1):

Try a `write user` from within your cron job. Like putting a

```
x y z * * write user%message%
```

into your `crontab`.

But be aware: that user must be logged in to be notified. A simple terminal session under GUI will not.

If using (a recent) `bash` or similar shell, setting `PROMPT_COMMAND` using an arbitrary file like

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='[ -f /tmp/msg ] && cat /tmp/msg && rm /tmp/msg'
```

and having a `crontab` entry like

```
x y z * * echo message > /tmp/msg
```

will display "message" once right before the next prompt.